# Laravel Adding One-To-Many on a Pivot table

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem trying to add a one-to-many relationship to a pivot table in Laravel, maybe its just not possible?

I have the following structure

We have Jobs, which Staff are assigned to, and for each of these assignments we need to store some data - similar but not quite like, log data. We also need to store pivot specific data for each assignment like pay rate and status, so we store these in the pivot

So we have a Job Model (i'm keeping these simple)

```
class Job extends \Eloquent {
 public function staff() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Staff')->withPivot('rate', 'status');
    }
}
```

A Staff Model

```
class Staff extends \Eloquent {
 public function jobs() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Job')->withPivot('rate', 'status');
    }

}
```

So that works fine and stores the data in the table 'job_staff'

But we need now to have a third table called 'job_events' which will store a log of all events which happened for that staff assignment to the job, so these events are not specific to either the staff or the job model, but to the assignment of the staff member to the job. As an example some events could be

- 'Arrived on Site'
- 'Clocked In'
- 'Took Break'
- 'Clocked Out'
- 'Left Site'

and so on.. So the pivot table of job_staff has many events, and an event belongs to one job_staff.

I'm assuming I need a pivot model for the job_staff table, and as such I've been trying to implement something like - https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2093#issuecomment-39154456

but with no success..

Would appreciate any pointers/ideas!

thanks
Cyril

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to consider this:

```
// custom pivot model can be accessed only in the context of relation
$jobStaff = $staff->jobs->first()->pivot;

// additional model for the pivot table can be accessed like any other
$jobStaff = JobStaff::whereStaffId($staff)->whereJobId($job)->first();
```

This is due to the fact, that `Pivot` is instantiated with a few arguments, creating relation context.

You have more control using `Model`, but pretty often you will find yourself in a situation, when you'd rather call `->pivot` on the related model, so **I suggest creating both**:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class JobStaffPivot extends Pivot {

    protected $table = 'job_events';
    // eloquent default name would be:
    // protected $table = 'event_job_staff';

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Event', 'assignement_id');
        // eloquent default would be:
        // return $this->hasMany('Event', 'job_staff_id');
    }
}

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class JobStaff extends Model {

    protected $table = 'job_events';

    public function job()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Job');
    }

    public function staff()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Staff');
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Event');
    }    
}
```

Additionally I would create below scope in order to do this:

```
$job = 5;
$staff = 10;
$jobStaff = JobStaff::for($job, $staff)->first();

// or
$job = Job::find($someId);
$staff = Staff::find($anotherId);
$jobStaff = JobStaff::forThe($job, $staff)->first();

// JobStaff model
public function scopeForThe($query, $job_id, $staff_id)
{
    if ($job_id instanceof Job) $job_id = $job_id->getKey();
    if ($staff_id instanceof Staff) $staff_id = $staff_id->getKey();

    $query->where(compact('job_id', 'staff_id'));
}
```

So finally you can use it like this:

```
$jobStaff = $staff->jobs->first()->pivot->events;

$jobStaff = JobStaff::forThe($job, $staff)->first()->events;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I got this working after a bit of tweaking to suit the intricacies of the actual implementation, but this was a massive help! thanks

Comment: How would you eager load the events in this case?

Comment: When you write:


`$jobStaff = JobStaff::for($job, $staff)->first();`


I guess you mean


`$jobStaff = JobStaff::forThe($job, $staff)->first();`